# Why doesn't my Perl script find my module even after I adjust @INC with FindBin?

Tags: perl, module, activeperl

I want to be able to use a module kept in the lib directory of my source code repository, and I want the only prerequisite for a developer to use the scripts that I'm writing is to have a *standard* Perl installation, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

In my scripts, I have

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/lib"; # store non standard modules here
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Win32::Console::ANSI;
print Term::ANSIColor::colored("this should be in color\n", "bold red");
```

and I put the module in ./lib. I verified that's the actual location where the module exists (by renaming it and causing it to fail). However, even if the module is in an arbitrary lib directory, it still seems to be a requirement that **ppm** be aware of the module.

I can not get my scripts to find/use it in lib without it being "installed" by **ppm** first. I would imagine that there should be some sort of way around this.

I know this may be an atypical request, but my goals are probably atypical. I just want a developer to do a checkout and immediately use some scripts without having to run some additional commands or use a package manager.

Thanks for any insight.

**EDIT:** I updated with a complete example. I also realized that if I uninstall it via ppm (but leave the pm in the referenced directory), I may have to change my syntax, and I was not considering that before. So maybe I have to give a full path or use require like jheddings or BipedalShark propose (ie. if it's not "installed", then I must use "require" and append ".pm" to it or use a BEGIN block.

If this is the case, then I have not found the correct syntax.

**EDIT 2:** Based on a comment below, I realize that I may have a flawed assumption. My reasoning is this: If I reference the actual code, the ".pm", directly then I should be able to use it without using a package manager. Maybe that's not the case, or if I want to do that maybe I have to do it a different way. Alternatively, I may have to refactor the code in the ".pm".

**EDIT 3:** I think that I was misunderstanding a few things. The error message in my IDE "Compilation failed in require", it's highlighting of the line that I was using to include the module, and the console error message of "Can't locate loadable object for module Win32::Console::ANSI"

I was reading that as a problem with loading the module itself, but it seems to be a problem that results from something the module itself is attempting to load. Interesting that this is only a problem since I didn't use ppm install though.

It is finding the actual module. I was able to verify that by commenting out the trouble lines.

Thanks for the help, but I'll have to spend some more time with it.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. PPM has no influence on anything except as an installer. What does it do when it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why are you talking about package managers? Your script shouldn't care anything about how the module got there. Is your real question something other than what you have posted?

Comment: What module is in lib/? What does lib/ look like?

Comment: IMHO, you can use PAR and compile it into .exe.

Comment: @Keith: any updates? did you find the problem?

Comment: Thx again for the help. See my note below the accepted answer. Sorry for the delay in getting back. Can only play with Perl on the weekends right now.

Comment: Sweet, I'm happy you found the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Can't-locate-loadable-object-for-module-%25s-in-%40INC) under "Can't locate loadable object for module ...":

> ```
>     (F) The module you loaded is trying to load an external library,
>     like for example, "foo.so" or "bar.dll", but the DynaLoader module
>     was unable to locate this library.  See DynaLoader.
> ```

You are correct that this problem is arising from something the module is trying to load -- that's what [Dynaloader](http://perldoc.perl.org/DynaLoader.html) does. However, the documentation for [Win32::Console::ANSI](http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.00/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm) makes no mention of any external library requirements.

Comment: When I ran "ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Win32-Console-ANSI.ppd", it also installed a dll in "C:\Perl\site\lib\auto\Win32\Console\ANSI" which I was unaware of and led me down this path. I thought the pm was the only download, hence all the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Are you preserving your module path structure in your `lib` directory?
i.e. your module should be in the path `$Bin/lib/Some/Module.pm`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean that I can rename it and cause it fail. I'm sure that the file in the lib path is the one that it's using. Thx.

Comment: I realized now that I may have to change my syntax if I don't have it "installed" via ppm. I tried require, use, and a Begin block specifying both a relative path and a absolute path have have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html)'s answer to [How do I add the directory my program lives in to the module/library search path?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_add_the_dir)

You appear to be doing it correctly, but you need to give us more if you expect to get help.

When you run that script, what ends up in `@INC`?  Put in a debugging line like:

```
 BEGIN {
      use lib ...;
      print "INC is \@INC\n"; 
      }
```

Check that that output shows the directory that you expect. If it doesn't, start bisecting the problem from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BEGIN {
    use FindBin qw($Bin);
}
use lib "$Bin/lib"; # store non standard modules here
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually install modules all the time and it seems to work.  I just copy directories and files into a location and use the "use lib" directive like you've shown.  Sometimes I miss a file and I get a runtime error that it's looking for a certain file and I go find the file on the Internet and put it in the right place and it works.  Not sure what's going on with your setup.  This should work.

I usually put the perl modules in the same directory as my script and then: use lib "."
But I don't know that it would matter.